# netplan isnt being applied and i am not getting an error message when i try to apply it

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

ive been trying to setup my 20.04 ubuntu server and get it connected to the internet through wifi, ive been following this website https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line, and im to the point that there are no errors being returned when i use netplan apply, but im also not getting anything that says success either from what i can tell i have the formatting of the netplan file correct but just in case here is what ive got

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp1s0:
            dhcp4: True
            optional: True
    version: 2
    wifis:
    wlo1:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "access point name here":
                   password: "password here"
            dhcp4: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect via Ethernet and install `wpasupplicant` and `net-tools`.

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install wpasupplicant net-tools`

Use this .yaml file... use the EXACT same spacing, indentation, and no tabs...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlo1:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "access point name here":
          password: "password here"
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: I think he also needs `net-tools`.

Comment: @chili555 Added. Thanks!

Comment: thank you, ive been working at this for 3 days now, i appreciate the help

Comment: @Trainz_driver If my answer helps to solve your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: i was wondering how to do that, thank you again for the help

Comment: @Trainz_driver Is it all working now?

Comment: yes it is thank you